# how to run protractor tests in docker-compose

Tags: javascript, docker, protractor, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver

I have problem with start test using protractor framework using docker image. When i start test in my local selenium server the tests is succeed. 
 but when i use docker image i got error **E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page http://localhost:4200/ : retries looking for angular exceeded**.

my config.js

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://hub:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['e2e/myTest.js'],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      args: ['--no-sandbox']
    }
  },
  chromeOnly: true
};
```

myTest.js

```
describe('example test', function() {
  var homePage = require('./pages/homePage.js');
  var homePage = new homePage();

  it('my test...', function() {

    browser.get('http://localhost:4200/');
....
```

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm install && ng serve -H 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "pretest": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "protractor config.js",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
```

Fragment of docker-compose.yml

```
  angular:...
  mypayara:...
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.9.1-actinium
    volumes:
        - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
        - hub
    environment:
        HUB_HOST: hub
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.9.1-actinium
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    depends_on:
        - angular
```

When i start test using command

> docker-compose exec angular sh -c "npm test"

i got that error

```
[18:51:48] E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page http://localhost:4200/ : retries looking for angular exceeded
F[18:51:59] E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page http://localhost:4200/ : retries looking for angular exceeded
F

Failures:
1) Register account test should create a account
  Message:
    Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:4200/.If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular.
                              Please see 
                              https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load
  Stack:
    Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:4200/.If this is not an Angular application, you may need to turn off waiting for Angular.
                              Please see 
                              https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load
        at executeAsyncScript_.then (/usr/src/app/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:720:27)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/src/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/src/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/src/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
        at asyncRun (/usr/src/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
        at /usr/src/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
    From: Task: Run it("should create a account") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/e2e/registertest.js:7:3)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/e2e/registertest.js:1:63)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

I have problem with connect with my docker apps. I am trying this test and result is success.

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() {
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');

    // You wrote your first test, cross it off the list
    todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
    var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
    expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

Do you have any idea what i can do with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

just to check if the reason is Angular, add this line to your code in 'it' block.

```
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

and watch what is happening

Comment: I check it, and when i add this line (missing await because i got error i     Failed: await is not defined) the browser is open in website but don't find next element in test. 
    Failed: No element found using locator: By(partial link text, exampleElement)


But test only 

    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.get('http://localhost:4200/');

Is success, do you have any idea what it's wrong?

Comment: it might be this element you are looking for is wrongly pointed. You could check it directly in your Browser console writing for example: `document.querySelector('div.dropdown__target > span.type-name')` and clicking enter you will find out it there any available locator on this path    P.S if await is not defined you might use controlFlow which is going to be cut out https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969 better to use async/await and off selenium promise manager --> `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false, in protractor config`

Comment: It wasn't problem with wrongly find element, because when i start my selenium server in local computer( with terminal using command webdriver-manager start ) and run test  the test run with success. 
but i need starting test in docker image because i use travis to automatic testing before merge pull request.

Comment: I got it, sorry, but here I dunno what to do, because I haven't encountered docker using so far